# How to mount a device of gpt type?

Tags: filesystems, mount, ssd, gpt

In Linux Mint 18.3 which boots from an HDD, I want to mount an external SSD.

When I run the command  `sudo fdisk -l`, I get all the drives and partitions as well as the SSD and when I run `sudo blkid`, I get the type and UUID of each of them. I know that gpt and mbr are the partition scheme for storage drives and ext4 or other extension of ext are the file system types in linux . However, the type for ssd is mentioned as gpt in the results from the aforementioned commands.

I tried to mount the SSD by editing the fstab file in /etc/fstab and adding this line ( I set the mount point as /media/ssd-mountpoint ) :

`uuid=<the uuid I got from blkid command> /media/ssd-mountpoint gpt defaults 0 2`

After using `mount -a`, however I get the error "the gpt type is unknown".

How can solve this to mount the ssd with gpt type?
Should I convert this format?

Comment: gpt is a partition type (vs dos ), and not a file system. Can you share the full out put of fdisk -l /dev/nvme0n1 ? IS this a new disk, or have you used it before on other systems. nvme01n1 is the full disk, if it has been partitioned, and formatted there should be a /dev/nvme01n1p1 as well.

Comment: On GPT disks isn't the command to use `parted` and not `fdisk`?

Comment: recent versions of fdisk do support gpt, but yes parted  might be better to use. I'm not sure what version of fdisk comes with mint 18.3

Comment: @Fitz very good point, thanks. But If I am not making a mistake, I think I need to first mount and then partition. Also, I don't want to divide it into several partitions because I need the whole space as just a single partition.

Comment: Mint 18.3 is based on ubuntu 16.04. If I run the fdisk command or the blkid without sudo, I cannot see the drive for ssd. However, if i add sudo to either of these commands, /dev/nvme0n1 and its further features appear.

Comment: You cannot mount a disk that has no filesystem on it: first you'll need to create a filesystem, then you can mount it. For a data disk, it is possible to just use the whole disk for a single filesystem, making partitioning optional. So the order of operations should be: first optionally partitioning and/or LVM, then creating a filesystem (specifying the desired FS type), then mounting it. For a data disk, partitioning is not mandatory but makes it easier to detect that the disk is in use, should the disk be accessed in another system for any reason.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can you help me with the commands to do each step? Or a tutorial for this?

Comment: @ArghavanM.hasani Here are a few for Ubuntu Linux, which should work for Mint Linux as well: [InstallingANewHardDrive](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallingANewHardDrive), [How do I add an additional hard drive?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/125257/how-do-i-add-an-additional-hard-drive), [Partitioning, Formatting, and Mounting a Hard Drive in Linux Ubuntu 18.04](https://medium.com/@sh.tsang/partitioning-formatting-and-mounting-a-hard-drive-in-linux-ubuntu-18-04-324b7634d1e0).

Comment: @Haxiel Thanks for the complete solutions. I just posted the first one as the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the solution to this problem, there are some information in various tutorials. The following steps are prerequisite towards making the new SSD usable:

**1. Partition**

**2. Create a File System and Format**

**3. Mount**

Number of partitions, into  which the SSD is divided, is optional. In this problem, it is inteded to divide it into a big single partition. Also, the file system type has been chosen as **ext4**. You can use either extensions of ext if you are going to use this partition only in Linux. The referrence to the complete (graphically or through the command line) solution with the commands for each step is made here:

> [Installing a New Storage Drive](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallingANewHardDrive)

Answer (score 3):

First let's reach to the the description of the first three fields of fstab format, from `man fstab`:

> The following is a typical example of an fstab entry:
>
> `LABEL=t-home2   /home      ext4    defaults,auto_da_alloc      0  2`
>
> The first field (fs_spec).
>   This field describes the block special device or remote filesystem to be mounted.
>
> The second field (fs_file).
>   This  field  describes  the  mount point (target) for the filesystem
>
> The third field (fs_vfstype).
>   This field describes the type of the filesystem.  Linux supports many filesystem types: ext4, xfs, btrfs, f2fs, vfat, ntfs, hfsplus,  tmpfs,  sysfs, proc, iso9660, udf, squashfs, nfs, cifs, and many more.  For more details, see mount(8).

The first parameter is device identification, it can be either `UUID=` or `/dev/nvme0n1` (or whatever else device name is reported by `blkid` 
 or `lsblk` utilities).

The second parameter is the mount point, i.e. where you want the mounted filesystem to appear in your local filesystem, for example `/mnt/mydisk`, assuming you have created such a directory **and it is entirely empty**.

Finally, `gpt` is not a type of filesystem, and that's what is expected in this field. In the context of `fdisk` and `gdisk` utilities, `gpt` is the partitioning scheme applied to divide the whole of the disk into partitions. This partitioning scheme corresponds to the type of partition table, residing in a (relatively) small block of data, around 1MB, starting at the zero position of the `/dev/nvme0` (note, no `n1` suffix) device. The actual filesystem is what resides in the `n1` partition (just past the partition table), and it will typically have one of the types listed my `man fstab`

You can use this command `sudo fsck -N /dev/nvme0n1` to tell you the filesystem to put there. More specifically this command will tell you which "flavour" of `fsck` command recognized this filesystem (this way telling you its type, in an roundabout way, e.g. if the filesystem was recognized by `fsck.ext4` that means you can put `ext4` there)

Comment: I editted my question and fixed my mistakes. I know that gpt is not the file system type but I should change it so that when I run the blkid or fdisk command again, the type is shown as a filesystem one not gpt. Does fsck command just report the suitable file system type? How can I convert the type to ext4 then?